# react-native\react.gradle' does not exist

Tags: react-native

I created an app using react native and I am trying to generate the apk. After doing everthing in the doc of http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content. An error occured and it says 
Could not read script react-native\react.gradle' as it does not exist.

Here is the error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Aaa\android\app\build.gradle' line: 68

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not read script 'C



*   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
*   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
*
*   // supply additional arguments to the packager
*   extraPackagerArgs: []
* ]
*/

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
```

Comment: Can you paste out your gradle config at android/app/build.gradle?

Comment: everything @max23_?

Comment: Probably from line 60 till line 70? (since it is complaining at line 68)

Comment: posted the error sir

Comment: Can you go up two levels from android/app/build.gradle and see if you manage to find the react.gradle at node_modules/react-native/react.gradle?

Comment: I cannot find the node_modules sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146177/discussion-between-max23-and-orange).

Comment: don't know if this is a related issue.  I use pnpm and get this problem.  Change to npm, ok !

Answer (score 45):

Go to the project's root folder and run `npm install` and it will generate the necessary files, including `react.gradle`

If you don't have node.js, you can download it from here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: If you're having issues in 2023 or after, in particular with updating an older app, see this answer instead about react.gradle being removed in 0.72 https://stackoverflow.com/a/76670901/636192

Answer (score 35):

For avoidance of future confusion, react.gradle was removed in 0.72 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v0720. If you're on that version it may be that you need to update your app/build.gradle file instead of the accepted answer

Comment: and how to update app/build.gradle

Comment: What should be the change then @personalnadir?

Comment: [This link to be exact - Android Specific removals](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#android-specific-5) - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#android-specific-5 and [this exact commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/d4a9bdc40e06bdda9565cc43ea5af5a13ff6f1cf)

Comment: @Irfanwani, @YM, in my case, I had to comment out `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` in my `android/app/build.gradle`

Comment: It's worth using the upgrade helper to see what specific changes to the various build files you'll need to make https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

Comment: these constant deprecations are going to be my demise

Answer (score 15):

If you are having this problem in **2023** in your `settings.gradle` replace `includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')` by :

- version between 0.71 and 0.72 :

> includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin')

- version > 0.72 :

> includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')

Comment: Thanks cbde, this solution worked for me. IMO this answer should be at the top.

Answer (score 3):

Comment out `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` from app/build.gradle It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this file `react.gradle` to a repository manually under "node_modules/react-native"

```
// Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.

// This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
// LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

def config = project.hasProperty("react") ? project.react : [];

def cliPath = config.cliPath ?: "node_modules/react-native/cli.js"
def composeSourceMapsPath = config.composeSourceMapsPath ?: "node_modules/react-native/scripts/compose-source-maps.js"
def bundleAssetName = config.bundleAssetName ?: "index.android.bundle"
def entryFile = config.entryFile ?: "index.android.js"
def bundleCommand = config.bundleCommand ?: "bundle"
def reactRoot = file(config.root ?: "../../")
def inputExcludes = config.inputExcludes ?: ["android/**", "ios/**"]
def bundleConfig = config.bundleConfig ? "${reactRoot}/${config.bundleConfig}" : null ;
def enableVmCleanup = config.enableVmCleanup == null ? true : config.enableVmCleanup
def hermesCommand = config.hermesCommand ?: "../../node_modules/hermesvm/%OS-BIN%/hermes"

def reactNativeDevServerPort() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeDevServerPort")
    return value != null ? value : "8081"
}

def reactNativeInspectorProxyPort() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeInspectorProxyPort")
    return value != null ? value : reactNativeDevServerPort()
}

def getHermesOSBin() {
  if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) return "win64-bin";
  if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_MAC)) return "osx-bin";
  if (Os.isOs(null, "linux", "amd64", null)) return "linux64-bin";
  throw new Exception("OS not recognized. Please set project.ext.react.hermesCommand " +
                      "to the path of a working Hermes compiler.");
}

// Make sure not to inspect the Hermes config unless we need it,
// to avoid breaking any JSC-only setups.
def getHermesCommand = {
  // If the project specifies a Hermes command, don't second guess it.
  if (!hermesCommand.contains("%OS-BIN%")) {
    return hermesCommand
  }

  // Execution on Windows fails with / as separator
  return hermesCommand
      .replaceAll("%OS-BIN%", getHermesOSBin())
      .replace('/' as char, File.separatorChar);
}

// Set enableHermesForVariant to a function to configure per variant,
// or set `enableHermes` to True/False to set all of them
def enableHermesForVariant = config.enableHermesForVariant ?: {
      def variant -> config.enableHermes ?: false
}

android {
    buildTypes.all {
        resValue "integer", "react_native_dev_server_port", reactNativeDevServerPort()
        resValue "integer", "react_native_inspector_proxy_port", reactNativeInspectorProxyPort()
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
    def isAndroidLibrary = plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.library")
    def variants = isAndroidLibrary ? android.libraryVariants : android.applicationVariants
    variants.all { def variant ->
        // Create variant and target names
        def targetName = variant.name.capitalize()
        def targetPath = variant.dirName

        // React js bundle directories
        def jsBundleDir = file("$buildDir/generated/assets/react/${targetPath}")
        def resourcesDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/${targetPath}")

        def jsBundleFile = file("$jsBundleDir/$bundleAssetName")
        def jsSourceMapsDir = file("$buildDir/generated/sourcemaps/react/${targetPath}")
        def jsIntermediateSourceMapsDir = file("$buildDir/intermediates/sourcemaps/react/${targetPath}")
        def jsPackagerSourceMapFile = file("$jsIntermediateSourceMapsDir/${bundleAssetName}.packager.map")
        def jsCompilerSourceMapFile = file("$jsIntermediateSourceMapsDir/${bundleAssetName}.compiler.map")
        def jsOutputSourceMapFile = file("$jsSourceMapsDir/${bundleAssetName}.map")

        // Additional node and packager commandline arguments
        def nodeExecutableAndArgs = config.nodeExecutableAndArgs ?: ["node"]
        def extraPackagerArgs = config.extraPackagerArgs ?: []

        def enableHermes = enableHermesForVariant(variant)

        def currentBundleTask = tasks.create(
            name: "bundle${targetName}JsAndAssets",
            type: Exec) {
            group = "react"
            description = "bundle JS and assets for ${targetName}."

            // Create dirs if they are not there (e.g. the "clean" task just ran)
            doFirst {
                jsBundleDir.deleteDir()
                jsBundleDir.mkdirs()
                resourcesDir.deleteDir()
                resourcesDir.mkdirs()
                jsIntermediateSourceMapsDir.deleteDir()
                jsIntermediateSourceMapsDir.mkdirs()
                jsSourceMapsDir.deleteDir()
                jsSourceMapsDir.mkdirs()
            }

            // Set up inputs and outputs so gradle can cache the result
            inputs.files fileTree(dir: reactRoot, excludes: inputExcludes)
            outputs.dir(jsBundleDir)
            outputs.dir(resourcesDir)

            // Set up the call to the react-native cli
            workingDir(reactRoot)

            // Set up dev mode
            def devEnabled = !(config."devDisabledIn${targetName}"
                || targetName.toLowerCase().contains("release"))

            def extraArgs = extraPackagerArgs;

            if (bundleConfig) {
                extraArgs = extraArgs.clone()
                extraArgs.add("--config");
                extraArgs.add(bundleConfig);
            }

            if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                commandLine("cmd", "/c", *nodeExecutableAndArgs, cliPath, bundleCommand, "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}",
                    "--reset-cache", "--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets-dest", resourcesDir,
                    "--sourcemap-output", enableHermes ? jsPackagerSourceMapFile : jsOutputSourceMapFile, *extraArgs)
            } else {
                commandLine(*nodeExecutableAndArgs, cliPath, bundleCommand, "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}",
                    "--reset-cache", "--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets-dest", resourcesDir,
                    "--sourcemap-output", enableHermes ? jsPackagerSourceMapFile : jsOutputSourceMapFile, *extraArgs)
            }

            if (enableHermes) {
                doLast {
                    def hermesFlags;
                    exec {
                        if (targetName.toLowerCase().contains("release")) {
                            // Can't use ?: since that will also substitute valid empty lists
                            hermesFlags = config.hermesFlagsRelease
                            if (hermesFlags == null) hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
                        } else {
                            hermesFlags = config.hermesFlagsDebug
                            if (hermesFlags == null) hermesFlags = []
                        }
                        commandLine(getHermesCommand(), "-emit-binary", "-out", jsBundleFile, jsBundleFile, *hermesFlags)
                    }
                    if (hermesFlags.contains("-output-source-map")) {
                        ant.move(
                            // Hermes will generate a source map with this exact name
                            // NOTE: name coincides with jsOutputSourceMapFile
                            file: "${jsBundleFile}.map",
                            tofile: jsCompilerSourceMapFile
                        );
                        exec {
                            // TODO: set task dependencies for caching

                            // Set up the call to the compose-source-maps script
                            workingDir(reactRoot)
                            if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                                commandLine("cmd", "/c", *nodeExecutableAndArgs, composeSourceMapsPath, jsPackagerSourceMapFile, jsCompilerSourceMapFile, "-o", jsOutputSourceMapFile)
                            } else {
                                commandLine(*nodeExecutableAndArgs, composeSourceMapsPath, jsPackagerSourceMapFile, jsCompilerSourceMapFile, "-o", jsOutputSourceMapFile)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            enabled config."bundleIn${targetName}" != null
              ? config."bundleIn${targetName}"
              : config."bundleIn${variant.buildType.name.capitalize()}" != null
                ? config."bundleIn${variant.buildType.name.capitalize()}"
                : targetName.toLowerCase().contains("release")
        }

        // Expose a minimal interface on the application variant and the task itself:
        variant.ext.bundleJsAndAssets = currentBundleTask
        currentBundleTask.ext.generatedResFolders = files(resourcesDir).builtBy(currentBundleTask)
        currentBundleTask.ext.generatedAssetsFolders = files(jsBundleDir).builtBy(currentBundleTask)

        // registerGeneratedResFolders for Android plugin 3.x
        if (variant.respondsTo("registerGeneratedResFolders")) {
            variant.registerGeneratedResFolders(currentBundleTask.generatedResFolders)
        } else {
            variant.registerResGeneratingTask(currentBundleTask)
        }
        variant.mergeResourcesProvider.get().dependsOn(currentBundleTask)

        // packageApplication for Android plugin 3.x
        def packageTask = variant.hasProperty("packageApplication")
            ? variant.packageApplicationProvider.get()
            : tasks.findByName("package${targetName}")
        if (variant.hasProperty("packageLibrary")) {
            packageTask = variant.packageLibrary
        }

        // pre bundle build task for Android plugin 3.2+
        def buildPreBundleTask = tasks.findByName("build${targetName}PreBundle")

        def resourcesDirConfigValue = config."resourcesDir${targetName}"
        if (resourcesDirConfigValue) {
            def currentCopyResTask = tasks.create(
                name: "copy${targetName}BundledResources",
                type: Copy) {
                group = "react"
                description = "copy bundled resources into custom location for ${targetName}."

                from(resourcesDir)
                into(file(resourcesDirConfigValue))

                dependsOn(currentBundleTask)

                enabled(currentBundleTask.enabled)
            }

            packageTask.dependsOn(currentCopyResTask)
            if (buildPreBundleTask != null) {
                buildPreBundleTask.dependsOn(currentCopyResTask)
            }
        }

        def currentAssetsCopyTask = tasks.create(
            name: "copy${targetName}BundledJs",
            type: Copy) {
            group = "react"
            description = "copy bundled JS into ${targetName}."

            if (config."jsBundleDir${targetName}") {
                from(jsBundleDir)
                into(file(config."jsBundleDir${targetName}"))
            } else {
                into ("$buildDir/intermediates")
                into ("assets/${targetPath}") {
                    from(jsBundleDir)
                }

                // Workaround for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2+ new asset directory
                into ("merged_assets/${variant.name}/merge${targetName}Assets/out") {
                    from(jsBundleDir)
                }

                // Workaround for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4+ new asset directory
                into ("merged_assets/${variant.name}/out") {
                    from(jsBundleDir)
                }
            }

            // mergeAssets must run first, as it clears the intermediates directory
            dependsOn(variant.mergeAssetsProvider.get())

            enabled(currentBundleTask.enabled)
        }

        packageTask.dependsOn(currentAssetsCopyTask)
        if (buildPreBundleTask != null) {
            buildPreBundleTask.dependsOn(currentAssetsCopyTask)
        }

        // Delete the VM related libraries that this build doesn't need.
        // The application can manage this manually by setting 'enableVmCleanup: false'
        //
        // This should really be done by packaging all Hermes releated libs into
        // two separate HermesDebug and HermesRelease AARs, but until then we'll
        // kludge it by deleting the .so files out of the /transforms/ directory.
        def isRelease = targetName.toLowerCase().contains("release")
        def libDir = "$buildDir/intermediates/transforms/"
        def vmSelectionAction = {
            fileTree(libDir).matching {
                if (enableHermes) {
                    // For Hermes, delete all the libjsc* files
                    include "**/libjsc*.so"

                    if (isRelease) {
                        // Reduce size by deleting the debugger/inspector
                        include '**/libhermes-inspector.so'
                        include '**/libhermes-executor-debug.so'
                    } else {
                        // Release libs take precedence and must be removed
                        // to allow debugging
                        include '**/libhermes-executor-release.so'
                    }
                } else {
                    // For JSC, delete all the libhermes* files
                    include "**/libhermes*.so"
                }
            }.visit { details ->
                def targetVariant = ".*/transforms/[^/]*/${targetPath}/.*"
                def path = details.file.getAbsolutePath().replace(File.separatorChar, '/' as char)
                if (path.matches(targetVariant) && details.file.isFile()) {
                  details.file.delete()
                }
            }
        }

        if (enableVmCleanup) {
            def task = tasks.findByName("package${targetName}")
            task.doFirst(vmSelectionAction)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

npm install alone will not do the trick.

You should run for android:

```
npm i @react-native-community/cli-platform-android
```

And then:

```
npm install
```

I ran this as admin and problem solved for me.

Answer (score 1):

**React.gradle** file add this file to `react modules` and then run your project it will solve your problem. this is official `react-native/react.gradle`

Let me know if any error occur.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

def config = project.hasProperty("react") ? project.react : [:];

def detectEntryFile(config) {
    if (System.getenv('ENTRY_FILE')) {
        return System.getenv('ENTRY_FILE')
    } else if (config.entryFile) {
        return config.entryFile
    } else if ((new File("${projectDir}/../../index.android.js")).exists()) {
        return "index.android.js"
    }

    return "index.js";
}

def cliPath = config.cliPath ?: "node_modules/react-native/cli.js"
def composeSourceMapsPath = config.composeSourceMapsPath ?: "node_modules/react-native/scripts/compose-source-maps.js"
def bundleAssetName = config.bundleAssetName ?: "index.android.bundle"
def entryFile = detectEntryFile(config)
def bundleCommand = config.bundleCommand ?: "bundle"
def reactRoot = file(config.root ?: "../../")
def inputExcludes = config.inputExcludes ?: ["android/**", "ios/**"]
def bundleConfig = config.bundleConfig ? "${reactRoot}/${config.bundleConfig}" : null ;
def enableVmCleanup = config.enableVmCleanup == null ? true : config.enableVmCleanup
def hermesCommand = config.hermesCommand ?: "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/%OS-BIN%/hermes"

def reactNativeDevServerPort() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeDevServerPort")
    return value != null ? value : "8081"
}

def reactNativeInspectorProxyPort() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeInspectorProxyPort")
    return value != null ? value : reactNativeDevServerPort()
}

def getHermesOSBin() {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) return "win64-bin";
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_MAC)) return "osx-bin";
    if (Os.isOs(null, "linux", "amd64", null)) return "linux64-bin";
    throw new Exception("OS not recognized. Please set project.ext.react.hermesCommand " +
                        "to the path of a working Hermes compiler.");
}

// Make sure not to inspect the Hermes config unless we need it,
// to avoid breaking any JSC-only setups.
def getHermesCommand = {
    // If the project specifies a Hermes command, don't second guess it.
    if (!hermesCommand.contains("%OS-BIN%")) {
        return hermesCommand
    }

    // Execution on Windows fails with / as separator
    return hermesCommand
            .replaceAll("%OS-BIN%", getHermesOSBin())
            .replace('/' as char, File.separatorChar);
}

// Set enableHermesForVariant to a function to configure per variant,
// or set `enableHermes` to True/False to set all of them
def enableHermesForVariant = config.enableHermesForVariant ?: {
    def variant -> config.enableHermes ?: false
}

android {
    buildTypes.all {
        resValue "integer", "react_native_dev_server_port", reactNativeDevServerPort()
        resValue "integer", "react_native_inspector_proxy_port", reactNativeInspectorProxyPort()
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
    def isAndroidLibrary = plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.library")
    def variants = isAndroidLibrary ? android.libraryVariants : android.applicationVariants
    variants.all { def variant ->
        // Create variant and target names
        def targetName = variant.name.capitalize()
        def targetPath = variant.dirName

        // React js bundle directories
        def jsBundleDir = file("$buildDir/generated/assets/react/${targetPath}")
        def resourcesDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/${targetPath}")

        def jsBundleFile = file("$jsBundleDir/$bundleAssetName")
        def jsSourceMapsDir = file("$buildDir/generated/sourcemaps/react/${targetPath}")
        def jsIntermediateSourceMapsDir = file("$buildDir/intermediates/sourcemaps/react/${targetPath}")
        def jsPackagerSourceMapFile = file("$jsIntermediateSourceMapsDir/${bundleAssetName}.packager.map")
        def jsCompilerSourceMapFile = file("$jsIntermediateSourceMapsDir/${bundleAssetName}.compiler.map")
        def jsOutputSourceMapFile = file("$jsSourceMapsDir/${bundleAssetName}.map")

        // Additional node and packager commandline arguments
        def nodeExecutableAndArgs = config.nodeExecutableAndArgs ?: ["node"]
        def extraPackagerArgs = config.extraPackagerArgs ?: []
        def npx = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? "npx.cmd" : "npx"

        def execCommand = []

        if (config.cliPath || config.nodeExecutableAndArgs) {
            if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                execCommand.addAll(["cmd", "/c", *nodeExecutableAndArgs, cliPath])
            } else {
                execCommand.addAll([*nodeExecutableAndArgs, cliPath])
            }
        } else {
            execCommand.addAll([npx, "react-native"])
        }

        def enableHermes = enableHermesForVariant(variant)

        def currentBundleTask = tasks.create(
            name: "bundle${targetName}JsAndAssets",
            type: Exec) {
            group = "react"
            description = "bundle JS and assets for ${targetName}."

            // Create dirs if they are not there (e.g. the "clean" task just ran)
            doFirst {
                jsBundleDir.deleteDir()
                jsBundleDir.mkdirs()
                resourcesDir.deleteDir()
                resourcesDir.mkdirs()
                jsIntermediateSourceMapsDir.deleteDir()
                jsIntermediateSourceMapsDir.mkdirs()
                jsSourceMapsDir.deleteDir()
                jsSourceMapsDir.mkdirs()
            }

            // Set up inputs and outputs so gradle can cache the result
            inputs.files fileTree(dir: reactRoot, excludes: inputExcludes)
            outputs.dir(jsBundleDir)
            outputs.dir(resourcesDir)

            // Set up the call to the react-native cli
            workingDir(reactRoot)

            // Set up dev mode
            def devEnabled = !(config."devDisabledIn${targetName}"
                || targetName.toLowerCase().contains("release"))

            def extraArgs = extraPackagerArgs;

            if (bundleConfig) {
                extraArgs = extraArgs.clone()
                extraArgs.add("--config");
                extraArgs.add(bundleConfig);
            }

            commandLine(*execCommand, bundleCommand, "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}",
                "--reset-cache", "--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets-dest", resourcesDir,
                "--sourcemap-output", enableHermes ? jsPackagerSourceMapFile : jsOutputSourceMapFile, *extraArgs)


            if (enableHermes) {
                doLast {
                    def hermesFlags;
                    def hbcTempFile = file("${jsBundleFile}.hbc")
                    exec {
                        if (targetName.toLowerCase().contains("release")) {
                            // Can't use ?: since that will also substitute valid empty lists
                            hermesFlags = config.hermesFlagsRelease
                            if (hermesFlags == null) hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
                        } else {
                            hermesFlags = config.hermesFlagsDebug
                            if (hermesFlags == null) hermesFlags = []
                        }

                        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                            commandLine("cmd", "/c", getHermesCommand(), "-emit-binary", "-out", hbcTempFile, jsBundleFile, *hermesFlags)
                        } else {
                            commandLine(getHermesCommand(), "-emit-binary", "-out", hbcTempFile, jsBundleFile, *hermesFlags)
                        }
                    }
                    ant.move(
                        file: hbcTempFile,
                        toFile: jsBundleFile
                    );
                    if (hermesFlags.contains("-output-source-map")) {
                        ant.move(
                            // Hermes will generate a source map with this exact name
                            file: "${jsBundleFile}.hbc.map",
                            tofile: jsCompilerSourceMapFile
                        );
                        exec {
                            // TODO: set task dependencies for caching

                            // Set up the call to the compose-source-maps script
                            workingDir(reactRoot)
                            if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                                commandLine("cmd", "/c", *nodeExecutableAndArgs, composeSourceMapsPath, jsPackagerSourceMapFile, jsCompilerSourceMapFile, "-o", jsOutputSourceMapFile)
                            } else {
                                commandLine(*nodeExecutableAndArgs, composeSourceMapsPath, jsPackagerSourceMapFile, jsCompilerSourceMapFile, "-o", jsOutputSourceMapFile)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            enabled config."bundleIn${targetName}" != null
                ? config."bundleIn${targetName}"
                : config."bundleIn${variant.buildType.name.capitalize()}" != null
                    ? config."bundleIn${variant.buildType.name.capitalize()}"
                    : targetName.toLowerCase().contains("release")
        }

        // Expose a minimal interface on the application variant and the task itself:
        variant.ext.bundleJsAndAssets = currentBundleTask
        currentBundleTask.ext.generatedResFolders = files(resourcesDir).builtBy(currentBundleTask)
        currentBundleTask.ext.generatedAssetsFolders = files(jsBundleDir).builtBy(currentBundleTask)

        // registerGeneratedResFolders for Android plugin 3.x
        if (variant.respondsTo("registerGeneratedResFolders")) {
            variant.registerGeneratedResFolders(currentBundleTask.generatedResFolders)
        } else {
            variant.registerResGeneratingTask(currentBundleTask)
        }
        variant.mergeResourcesProvider.get().dependsOn(currentBundleTask)

        // packageApplication for Android plugin 3.x
        def packageTask = variant.hasProperty("packageApplication")
            ? variant.packageApplicationProvider.get()
            : tasks.findByName("package${targetName}")
        if (variant.hasProperty("packageLibrary")) {
            packageTask = variant.packageLibrary
        }

        // pre bundle build task for Android plugin 3.2+
        def buildPreBundleTask = tasks.findByName("build${targetName}PreBundle")

        def resourcesDirConfigValue = config."resourcesDir${targetName}"
        if (resourcesDirConfigValue) {
            def currentCopyResTask = tasks.create(
                name: "copy${targetName}BundledResources",
                type: Copy) {
                group = "react"
                description = "copy bundled resources into custom location for ${targetName}."

                from(resourcesDir)
                into(file(resourcesDirConfigValue))

                dependsOn(currentBundleTask)

                enabled(currentBundleTask.enabled)
            }

            packageTask.dependsOn(currentCopyResTask)
            if (buildPreBundleTask != null) {
                buildPreBundleTask.dependsOn(currentCopyResTask)
            }
        }

        def currentAssetsCopyTask = tasks.create(
            name: "copy${targetName}BundledJs",
            type: Copy) {
            group = "react"
            description = "copy bundled JS into ${targetName}."

            if (config."jsBundleDir${targetName}") {
                from(jsBundleDir)
                into(file(config."jsBundleDir${targetName}"))
            } else {
                into ("$buildDir/intermediates")
                into ("assets/${targetPath}") {
                    from(jsBundleDir)
                }

                // Workaround for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2+ new asset directory
                into ("merged_assets/${variant.name}/merge${targetName}Assets/out") {
                    from(jsBundleDir)
                }

                // Workaround for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4+ new asset directory
                into ("merged_assets/${variant.name}/out") {
                    from(jsBundleDir)
                }
            }

            // mergeAssets must run first, as it clears the intermediates directory
            dependsOn(variant.mergeAssetsProvider.get())

            enabled(currentBundleTask.enabled)
        }

        packageTask.dependsOn(currentAssetsCopyTask)
        if (buildPreBundleTask != null) {
            buildPreBundleTask.dependsOn(currentAssetsCopyTask)
        }

        // Delete the VM related libraries that this build doesn't need.
        // The application can manage this manually by setting 'enableVmCleanup: false'
        //
        // This should really be done by packaging all Hermes releated libs into
        // two separate HermesDebug and HermesRelease AARs, but until then we'll
        // kludge it by deleting the .so files out of the /transforms/ directory.
        def isRelease = targetName.toLowerCase().contains("release")
        def libDir = "$buildDir/intermediates/transforms/"
        def vmSelectionAction = {
            fileTree(libDir).matching {
                if (enableHermes) {
                    // For Hermes, delete all the libjsc* files
                    include "**/libjsc*.so"

                    if (isRelease) {
                        // Reduce size by deleting the debugger/inspector
                        include '**/libhermes-inspector.so'
                        include '**/libhermes-executor-debug.so'
                    } else {
                        // Release libs take precedence and must be removed
                        // to allow debugging
                        include '**/libhermes-executor-release.so'
                    }
                } else {
                    // For JSC, delete all the libhermes* files
                    include "**/libhermes*.so"
                }
            }.visit { details ->
                def targetVariant = ".*/transforms/[^/]*/${targetPath}/.*"
                def path = details.file.getAbsolutePath().replace(File.separatorChar, '/' as char)
                if (path.matches(targetVariant) && details.file.isFile()) {
                    details.file.delete()
                }
            }
        }

        if (enableVmCleanup) {
            def task = tasks.findByName("package${targetName}")
            task.doFirst(vmSelectionAction)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do
**npm install**

and and all the problems are over.

Comment: This answer is too broad... it doesnt solve the issue as to why react.gradle fails to read.

Comment: Herwindra, i already run "npm install" but in my case the problem persists... And when i run "react-native run-android" a message said don't recognize "run-android" and that i have to run "npm install". So i don't understand kkkkk

Comment: Didn't get the solution with this.

Answer (score 0):

Which means there is no node-modules in your project directory. please do yarn install or npm install to create node-modules then run the application in android studio.

Comment: Before answering a question, I recommend reading through existing answers. The top answer on this post (from three years ago) recommends the same thing, with a bit of additional detail. Your answer may be correct, but it's not contributing anything beyond the existing answers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26046597)

Comment: @lordhog: It _does_ provide an answer. It suggests running e.g., `npm install`. It’s a _redundant_ answer, but it’s still an _answer_.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old question, but I ran into this issue today and I hope this helps keep someone else from pulling their hair out.

I'm using yarn workspaces which causes node_modules to be installed at the workspace root (one level above where they would normally be.)
This isn't a problem for the node/typescript part of the project.
However, since gradle *also* references files inside of node modules, it gets confused and gives up.

So far, I've only run into this on Windows.

Comment: Did you find a resolution?

Comment: My resolution was to use Lerna instead of Yarn Workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me :

- Delete node.modules file
- npm install in your commande line

Then it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when trying to run an Android project. To solve it,
I first deleted the 'node_modules' directory.
Then, I opened my project folder in Finder, right-clicked to access 'Get Info,' and granted read and write permissions.
I also selected 'Apply to enclosed items.' I repeated this process for the 'Android' folder.
After that,
I reinstalled the node modules and ran the project, and it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Note: Make sure that you are running this command from the location where you have the gradlew file or else you will get an error.

> `chmod +x gradlew`

Answer (score 0):

For 'react-native' >= 0.73.x is just comment/remove the line below in `android\app\build.gradle` as the @Irfanwani told.

```bash
// apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
```

Answer (score -1):

had to comment out apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle" in my android/app/build.gradle this worked for me