# CI pipeline for ReactNative Mobile App not working

Tags: azure-devops, react-native, mobile-application

Our team is developing a mobile app using React Native. I have taken the code from Azure Repo and cloned it to my local system to build the system once , before start creating the Azure Pipeline for it.

I have installed the below in my system as instructed by the developer:
node version 12.8.3
npm version 7.6.1
python 2.7.15
JDk 8.0.2410.7

I have ran the below commands to build the android source code :

```js
npm install -g react-native-cli
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

The package.json has the below scripts defined:

```js
"main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
    }
```

Now that the build is successful in my local system, I am creating a pipeline for the CI pipeline. Below is the code:

```js
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: npm install
  displayName: 'Install node dependencies'

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: '/android'
    gradleWrapperFile: '/android/gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: 'assembleRelease'
```

What I have learned from the many examples I have seen is, Gradle task will be bundling and generating apk file. But the pipeline that I have created is throwing error as given below:

```js
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'MobileApp'.
 Could not read script '/home/vsts/work/1/s/MobileApp/node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy' as it does not exist.
```

And this is what I see in the settings.gradle file:

```js
rootProject.name = 'MobileApp'

apply from: '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'
includeUnimodulesProjects()

apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

include ':app'
```

I feel like multiple errors are the altogether, not just settings file. When I ran the build in local system, it went fine. But when I ran the pipeline its showing full issues. Appreciate any inputs on this.

P.S : I have started working in devops recently only. I was able to set the pipelines for Dotnet services and Angular Projects. But Mobile App is pretty new to me.

Comment: You can try to run `npm install react-native-unimodules`. Here is a [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437554/react-native-react-gradle-does-not-exist) with similar issue.

Comment: okay , I will try and update here

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT I tried,but I am not getting the apk files post running the same. Even though the build is showing successful there are no outputs.I am still checking it. I tried in my local system as well, Same result

Answer (score 0):

add this step post gradle task

```
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish APK to artifacts'
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: 'packages/abc-mobile/android/app/build' #mention your path
      ArtifactName: 'android'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
```