# autolinking.gradle does not exist error when excuting expo run:android

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo, build.gradle, gradlew

I'm trying to run my android expo project on android by executing `expo run:android`
and i'm getting this error

[image]

this is my `settings.gradle` file

```
rootProject.name = 'K53Learners'

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../scripts/autolinking.gradle");
useExpoModules()

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

include ':app'
includeBuild(new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native-gradle-plugin/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile())

if (settings.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && settings.newArchEnabled == "true") {
  include(":ReactAndroid")
  project(":ReactAndroid").projectDir = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../ReactAndroid");
  include(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine")
  project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine").projectDir = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../ReactAndroid/hermes-engine");
}
```

Comment: One possible cause of this error is that the `rootProject.name` setting is set to an invalid value. For example, if the value of `rootProject.name` contains invalid characters or is too long, it could cause this error.

Comment: You may also to try deleting the `settings.gradle`. And try to run again `expo run:android`

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @BloggerKlik https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437554/react-native-react-gradle-does-not-exist#comment135893041_49379568

Answer (score 0):

In my case i use bareworkflow expo, and run:

`npm audit fix --force`

this broke the build, but I ran it again and then it fixed it